# how can I get all post of user's in django

Tags: python, django

I want to get users posts but I don't know how to do it. Which I neded to use relationships. I would be appreciate if you could help me

User = a --> post 1, post 2 post 3

User = b --> post4 , post 3, post 5

I want that my project behaves like this.so, I want to query posts according to user

Comment: Could you be bit more specific? What is your model? Please post some code to nail down the problem.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If you were asked this question, what would you need to solve it? For example, we have no idea what model structure your app has

Comment: I tried to explain more detaild. you can look at

Comment: Your example has post 3 belonging to both user a and user b.  Is this correct?  If so, it complicates things a lot.  Otherwise, you could just say `Post.objects.filter(owner=user)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the answer depends on your `model` setup.

For example, if your models.py looks like this:

```
class Post(models.Model)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user
```

Then if you wanted **all** of the posts of the user that is logged in, you would use this code, for example, in your request you would use `filter` to filter out the appropriate posts that match a certain parameter (in this case `user`):

```
def index_page(request):
    logged_in_user = request.user
    logged_in_user_posts = Post.objects.filter(user=user)

    return render(request, 'index.html', {'posts': logged_in_user_posts})
```

Then, for example, you could manipulate this **queryset** in your `index.html` file as such:

```
<div>
{% for post in posts %}

    Username: {{ post.user.username }}
    Post: {{ post.content }}

    <br>

{% endfor %}
</div>
```