# making user post show on profile page

Tags: python, django

Hey guys I am looking to do something like what this question is but I dont see whats wrong with my code. [Something like this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34731589/how-can-i-get-all-post-of-users-in-django). I'm just trying to make a profile page for my site and I wanted to add all the user posts on the profile page but I just dont seem to be able to get it to work. I tried googling the solution and even tried other stackoverflow questions but couldnt if the right answer. If anyone could help me I would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

I also know its the same question as the one I linked but below is me trying what the guy in the solution did and I just didnt seem to make it work and been going over it for couple of hours sadly to say but what can I say still learning :p

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


def upload_location(posts, filename):
    return ("%s/%s" %(posts.author, filename))

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_location, null=True, blank=True, height_field="height_field", width_field="width_field")
    height_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    width_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    description = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    votes_total = models.IntegerField(default=0)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.user.username

def pub_date_pretty(self):
    return self.pub_date.strftime('%b %d %Y')
```

views.py, I am importing my Post class from a different app so I did think that could be the problem.

```
from posts.models import Post

def view_profile(request):
    logged_in_user = request.user
    logged_in_user_posts = Post.objects.filter(user=author)

    return render(request, 'accounts/profile.html', {'posts': logged_in_user_posts})
```

html file

```
<div>
{% for post in posts %}

    Post: {{ post.author }}

    <br>

{% endfor %}
</div>
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

app_name = 'accounts'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^register/', views.signup, name="signup"),
    url(r'^login/', views.loginuser, name="login"),
    url(r'^logout/', views.logoutview, name="logout"),
    url(r'^profile/', views.view_profile, name="viewprofile"),
]
```

**Added after reading first answer posted below**

after looking at the following post below I got this error:

FileNotFoundError at /accounts/profile/ [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\Mohamed\Desktop\thegallerybox\media_cdn\imag‌e

Am I receiving this error because in my html file I'm not calling the user image from the user folder in the media folder. I am uploading the images based on the author shown in my models.py so I thought that might have to do with getting the image in the html file

`def upload_location(posts, filename):
      return ("%s/%s" %(posts.author, filename))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to filter based on `author` since that's what is defined in your `Post` model, and you want to check against the currently logged in user.

Try making the following change

```
logged_in_user_posts = Post.objects.filter(author=logged_in_user)
```

Comment: when i do that i get this: FileNotFoundError at /accounts/profile/
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Mohamed\\Desktop\\thegallerybox\\media_cdn\\image

Comment: added the url.py folder as you requested